# How to map a source table(120 columns) with a target table(40 columns) in spark with scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe, etl

I'm a beginner in scala, spark.

Here is my problem.

I have two tables.
A source table has 120 columns and multiple rows.
(product_no, product_name, product_size, product_price, discount_rate, ...).
Another target table has 40 columns and multiple rows.
(items_id, seller, items_price, items_name, ...).

And I want to map source table with target table.
And I have a csv file, and source table's data are in the csv file.

(based on Target table)
 1. items_id  <=>  product_no
 2. seller = null or ""(empty string). because source table doesn't have seller column.
 3. items_price  <=>  product_price
 4. items_name  <=>  product_name
 5. ...

I try to use function withColumn(), withColumnRenamed(), drop(). But it has so many columns, and I got an error in build. (org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException, java.lang.StackOverflowError)

I hope to solve this problem with "class" or "dataframe.map()" if that's possible.

**
Finally, I want a dataframe from target table. So, I will insert into hadoop table with hiveql using the dataframe.

please Help. thank you.

```
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
hiveContext.sql("create table if not exists taget_table (items_id string, seller string, items_price string, items_name string, ....")

val sourceData = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true").load(".../csv.file")
...
...
(What should I do...?)
```